# Minimum number of cameras required to cover all nodes in graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I came across a problem in leetcode named "Binary Tree Camera".

I was wondering how to approach this similar problem:-

You have to place cameras at nodes of a graph such that whole graph is covered. A camera on a node monitors all its immediate neighbour nodes and itself. Find the minimum number of cameras required to cover all nodes.

Comment: Does the camera on a node covers that node?

Comment: @thepirat000 yes.

Comment: Why not just read the open ["discuss"](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-cameras/discuss) section? It has many solutions.

Comment: this question is different. Here you have a graph which can have cycles, disconnected components. @גלעדברקן

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), which there are many well-known algorithms for. To model it as an instance of the set cover problem, map each node to the set of nodes which a camera at that node would cover. The original problem of choosing the fewest number of nodes is equivalent to choosing the fewest number of those sets.

In general, this is an "NP Hard" problem, meaning there is no known algorithm which always gives the minimum covering and also scales well to large instances of the problem. Since the problem asks for the minimum, a heuristic algorithm is not suitable, so you will need to do something like a [backtracking search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).

Comment: I reached the same conclusion but wanted to confirm if it was correct. What is the best approximation algorithm to go for?

Comment: Your question asks for "the minimum", so I took that to mean you wanted an exact algorithm. If you just need an approximation, the greedy algorithm is the simplest way (i.e. keep choosing the set which covers the most elements not covered so far); it will always give a cover that is at most (1 + log n) times larger than the true minimum, which you won't beat by more than a factor of 2 without an exponential-time algorithm. For other heuristics, search for "minimum set cover heuristic" or "minimum set cover approximation" - there are several papers with improvements on the greedy algorithm.

Comment: It's the Minimum Dominating Set and is different from Set Cover. Each instance of this problem trivially maps to a Set Cover instance though.

Comment: *"Each instance of this problem trivially maps to a Set Cover instance though."* That is what my answer says. As Wikipedia notes, *"there are straightforward ... bijections between the two problems"*.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is called the Minimum [Dominating Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set) and is NP-hard for the general graph case. Algorithms exist that approach this problem by either approximation, parameterization or restricting the class of graphs. See the Wikipedia link for details.